# Deploying to OS X 10.6 and "-fobj-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime"

Tags: compilation, automatic-ref-counting, cpu-architecture, objective-c-runtime

**Background:**

I'm building an app for OS X with deployment target of 10.6.  I have not converted my app to ARC completely, but I am adding a few new classes which would benefit from ARC, so I have set the `-fobj-arc` compiler flag for those classes.

Compiling fails for *Universal 32/64-bit Intel* architecture, with error *-fobj-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime*.

Building for 64-bit only succeeds.

I'm not well versed in low level architecture. My question is: what is the effect of building for 64-bit Intel only? Does this prevent the app from running on 10.6 completely? Or only some machines running 10.6?

Comment: To my knowledge, the last mac that had a 32 bit processor was the September 2006 Mac mini, so if you're using anything more recent than that, you have no consequences at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 32-bit runtime of OS X's Objective-C is fairly old. Apple updated the runtime when they moved to 64-bit, but didn't do much with the 32-bit runtime.

As for building for 64-bit only: Most Macs have 64-bit processors in them now. However, 10.6 does support 32-bit-only computers as well: you *will* be leaving those users in the dust.

[I have created a header](https://gist.github.com/MaddTheSane/d236feae5645b4b35719) that will help with the transition to ARC, in that you can target ARC on 64-bit hardware and not on 32-bit hardware and both will work. However, this really defeats the purpose of ARC, as you will still need to manage retain and release, they'll just be commented-out when building ARC code.

Comment: Where can we find this header file that will help with the transition to ARC?