# error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, awesomium

I am attempting to build this tutorial from Awesomium in XCode:  http://wiki.awesomium.com/tutorials/tutorial-2-displaying-your-first-page.html

I have set the Architectures to 32 Bit Intel, and the Valid Architectures set to i386 only as instructed on this page:  http://wiki.awesomium.com/getting-started/setting-up-on-macosx.html

When I build get the following error:

```
error: -fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this is duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361445/deploying-to-os-x-10-6-and-fobj-arc-is-not-supported-on-platforms-using-the-le

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Unfortunately, Awesomium requires the architecture settings to be 32 bit only, per the Awesomium OS X setup guide:  http://wiki.awesomium.com/getting-started/setting-up-on-macosx.html